# How to select dynamic id with jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How can I get a dynamic `id` from each `<tr>`  `<a>` tag. I'm trying with the code below. Any help would be appreciated.

```
 <td>
     <a class="btn" id="product-update{{product.id}}" href="{% url 'accpack:product_update' pk=product.id %}">{{product.product_code}}</a>
 </td>

 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("div[id^='product-update']").click(function () {
            $("#collapseTwo").addClass( "show");
        });
    });
```

Comment: You could use `$("div[id^='product-update']")`

Comment: @Carsten Løvbo Andersen can you please take look at my updated post? Would it be like that?

Comment: You haven't described what the problem is. What is not working`? Also you haven't included the element for collapseTwo

Comment: The easiest solution is to **stop using dynamic IDs** there's no need for them and there are better solutions.  `<a class='btn product-update-button'>` `$(".product-update-button'")`.   Classes don't mean styles.   Styles use classes, the classes themselves are not styles so can be used for anything, such as identifying product update buttons

Comment: *would it be like that* - what happened when you tried it?